# Why this code generate very big executable in go (around 81M)?

Tags: go

I'm new to golang. I wrote code like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

const (
    BIG_NUM = 10 * 1000 * 1000
)

type BigData [BIG_NUM]uint64

func (self BigData) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d\n", self[0])
}

func (self *BigData) Clear() {
    *self = BigData{}
}

func main() {
    data := new(BigData)
    fmt.Println(data)
}
```

After compiling, the executable is around 81M:

```
$ ls -l
-rwxr-xr-x  1 tchen  522017917  81533376 Dec 19 08:44 test
-rw-r--r--  1 tchen  522017917       290 Dec 19 08:44 test.go
```

When I remove Clear() function, the executable goes to normal size. So why this Clear() function generate so big executable? It should be called at runtime, not compiling time, right?

------------ further investigation -----------

Enlightened by @FUZxxl, I modified the code to use a global variable in Clear(). This time the file size went back to normal. So global variables are putting to .bss section correctly.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

const (
    BIG_NUM = 10 * 1000 * 1000
)

type BigData [BIG_NUM]uint64

var (
    bigData = BigData{}
)

func (self BigData) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d\n", self[0])
}

func (self *BigData) Clear() {
    *self = bigData
}

func main() {
    data := new(BigData)
    fmt.Println(data)
}
```

The compiled executable:

```
$ ls -l
-rwxr-xr-x  1 tchen  522017917  1534384 Dec 19 10:55 test
-rw-r--r--  1 tchen  522017917      318 Dec 19 10:55 test.go
```

------------ latest update -----------

So far it seems this is a compiler issue. A bug has been submitted: https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=6993. You can follow up it if you're interested.

Before there's any solution to it, you should avoid using `x := Y{}` in your function. A workaround is (thanks to ality@pbrane.org):

```
func (self *BigData) Clear() {
-   *self = BigData{}
+   var zero BigData
+   *self = zero
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like `BigData{}` in the `Clear()` function is causing an array of 80,000,000 bytes = `sizeof uint64 * 10 * 1000 * 1000` to be hardcoded into the binary.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes that is the cause. But why this happened? Shouldn't this function be called only at runtime? Why compiler hardcoded it into executable?

Comment: My guess is that because `BigData{}` is a compile-time constant, the compiler thinks it is performing an optimization on your behalf.

Comment: @Andrey I doubt it's an "optimization".

Comment: @user2864740 you're probably right.  The right way to populate the array is to iterate through it and set its entries to 0 one at a time, and the compiler doesn't reason about this correctly.

Comment: What boggles my mind is that the Go compiler does not use the bss section for BigData{}. I think this is a bug. Very large but empty arrays should not have any effect on executable size.

Comment: @FUZxxl agree. I did further tweak on code - add a global variable - `var bigData = BigData{}` and change `Clear()` with `*self = bigData`. This time the file size come back to normal. So seems the compiler use the bss only for global variables.

Comment: For anyone interested, this issue seems to be covered here: http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=5373

Comment: @Tyr [Looks like Dave Cheney would like this bug logged.](https://twitter.com/davecheney/status/413794697966936064) Great find!

Comment: @Matt thanks for reminding. Bug submitted. https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=6993